# Blender in Unity3D, particules

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, particles

I got question about Blender and Unity.
When i make 3D modele in Blender with hair particles, i'm able to import the 3D modele in Unity but as a bald modele, like if i can not have particules.

so, my question is :

is that normal ?
if it is, should i stop to make particule ?

Answer (score 0):

i finally found how do this.

It's pretty simple, particule isn't imported from blender, we have to convert in Mesh/Curve before.

To convert we have to go in Modifier panel and select "Convert"
after this, select the new object.
In the top menu, choose Object => Convert to => Curve

That's it, you can save and try to import, of course you will need to change some settings but i'm far to be a professional to explain what and why